# how to put two background colour for tag

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to apply two background color for the same tag. I tried before and after it did not work

```
.try :before
{
background-color: rgb(174, 202, 204);
    left: 23px;
    top: 254px;
    width: 252px;
    height: 39px;
    z-index: 17;
}
.try :after 
{
background-color: rgb(174, 202, 204);
    left: 23px;"little bit of changing  here 
    top: 254px;
    width: 252px;
    height: 39px;
    z-index: 17;
}
```

and my HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-4 backcolor">
    <div class="row furckas">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="try">Furntiture</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please if you have any other idea please share them with me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i will try to design css for tag , but as you see i need the same background with different style for the same tag <h2 > Furntiture </h2> when i apply one the other dose not work

Comment: Are you trying to say something like you want half of h2 red and half of h2 black ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I can't get your actual problem but You can't use 2 background colors for the same tag at the same time. You can use 2 background colors if you want to use properties like hover, onclick etc.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!